# get data from database and bind to html table using jquery in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am trying to get the data from database and bind to html table using jquery in php. results showing correctly. but i want to fetch the data into inside text box which means the fetched data should be editable. please do my needs.

my code is.

```
$.ajax({

           type: "POST",
          url: "add_temp_purchase",
         cache: false,
         data: 'itemnum='+itemnum+'&quantity='+quantity+'&customer_id='+customer_id,
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(returnhtml) {
             //alert(customer_id);
               $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "gettempid",
                cache: false,
               data: 'customer_id='+customer_id,
               dataType: "html",
              beforeSend: function() {
                                                                                    $('#metable').html('loading please wait...');
                                                                                             },
                         success: function(htmldata) {
                 var order_id = order_id;
                  var customer_id = customer_id;
                  var item_id = itemnum;
                  var count = quantity;

                 alert(customer_id);


                 $(".metable").find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + order_id +
                '</td><td><input type="text">' + customer_id +
                      '</td><td><input type="text">' + item_id +
                '</td><td><input type="text">' + count +
                    '</td></tr>');


                        }
                       });
```

My html code is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover metable table-bordered" id="editable-sample">
                              <thead>
                              <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                                  <th>Customer Id</th>
                                  <th>Item Number</th>
                                  <th>Quantity</th>

                              </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                              <?php
         foreach ($tempresults as $result)
               {
               ?>
                              <tr class="">
            <td><input type="text" name="order_id" id="order_id" value="<?php echo $result->order_id;?>"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="<?php echo $result->customer_id;?>"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="item_id" id="item_id" value="<?php echo $result->item_id;?>"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="count" id="count" value="<?php echo $result->count;?>"></td>

                              </tr>

                               <?php
          }
                   ?>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                                                                Thanks,
```

Comment: In the returned data of your ajax, set the value of each of your text fields by doing `$("#order_id").val(result.correspondingdata);` (assuming that you returned the data in array).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but did you try this?

```
$(".metable").find('tbody').append('<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="' + order_id + '"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="' + customer_id + '"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="' + item_id + '"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="' + count + '"></td>
</tr>');
```